# "drools-wiring-dynamic" error when modifying a Drools fact

Tags: drools, kogito

I auto-generated a drools project using the archetype:
`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.kie -DarchetypeArtifactId=kie-drools-exec-model-ruleunit-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=8.33.0.Final`

Modified the Measurement class to add:

```
    public void setVal(final String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
```

Added the following statement to the consequence of the original rule:

```
rule "will execute per each Measurement having ID color"
when
    $measure: /measurements[ id == "color", $colorVal : val ]
then
    $measure.setVal("BS");
end
```

When I ran the RuleTests (both via IntelliJ and via maven) I got the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You're trying to dynamically define a class, please add the module org.drools:drools-wiring-dynamic to your classpath.

    at org.drools.wiring.statics.StaticProjectClassLoader$DummyInternalTypesClassLoader.defineClass(StaticProjectClassLoader.java:83)
    at org.drools.wiring.api.classloader.ProjectClassLoader.defineType(ProjectClassLoader.java:208)
    at org.drools.wiring.api.classloader.ProjectClassLoader.tryDefineType(ProjectClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.drools.wiring.api.classloader.ProjectClassLoader.loadType(ProjectClassLoader.java:181)
    at org.drools.wiring.api.classloader.ProjectClassLoader.loadClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:135)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

The workaround is to add the following to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-wiring-dynamic</artifactId>
            <version>8.33.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Does anyone know why this needs to be added manually? I don't see anything about this in the documentation.

Link to a replicator: https://github.com/code4dc/kogito-examples/tree/drools-wiring-replicator/kogito-springboot-examples/ruleunit-springboot-example

This uses Kogito instead of pure Drools but the error is still the same. Just go into the `ruleunit-springboot-example` dir and run `mvn clean verify`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot reproduce.

I've been following the steps you listed, [and up to this commit](https://github.com/tarilabs/tarilabs-20230201-so75304743/commit/5558203010c5e7135434def79fd656ecb7a224f2) it works as expected (tests are passing, no stacktraces), without having to add any additional dependencies.

Further, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but a more idiomatic way to write the rule for that mod would be:

```
rule "will execute per each Measurement having ID color"
when
    $measure: /measurements[ id == "color", $colorVal : val != "BS" ]
then
    controlSet.add($colorVal);
    modify( $measure ) {
        setVal( "BS" )
    }
end
```

So the controlSet line is used to make sure non-regression during the test, the fact is modified with the `modify() { expression }` form which is idiomatic, and to avoid re-entry for property reactivity, we exclude the hardcoded value of `"BS"`.

In the test case for aligning with your use case in the way I could only guess, I've added:

```java
assertTrue( queryResult.stream().map(Measurement::getVal).allMatch("BS"::equals) );
```

and tests are again passing, as expected ([proved in this following commit](https://github.com/tarilabs/tarilabs-20230201-so75304743/commit/8f577b6e3a98b938ecd122771e18eead0b4bde98)).

Comment: I am sorry, even though I still get this error in my original project code (when `drools-wiring-dynamic` is commented out) I can no longer replicate it in my test project. Not sure what I changed but I'll keep trying to figure it out. 

Thank you for the fast answer and my apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I think I have a replicator based on the existing kogito-examples. Can you let me know if you are able to see the error: https://github.com/code4dc/kogito-examples/tree/drools-wiring-replicator/kogito-springboot-examples/ruleunit-springboot-example

You should just need the `ruleunit-springboot-example` project, it's now independent of its parent in my version.

Comment: the comment above makes it an entirely different question. Based on the original question, using Archetype, steps, demonstrated in my answer that cannot reproduce, as you confirmed in your earlier comment. I would encourage to mark this as answered, and feel free to reach out on mailing-list kogito-development if you have specific questions about Kogito.